# How do I add a newline to the flash error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to format the flash error and ran into some issues:

```
errors = ["error1 msg", "error2 msg", "error3 msg"]   
flash[:error] = errors.join("\n")
```

I expected to see them displayed in three separate lines, however, I got `"error1 msg error2 msg error3 msg"` instead.

What did happen to the newline I used to join the string?

Answer (score 19):

HTML does not use newlines for line-breaks, it uses `<br/>` tags. Also, you must use html_safe to make sure the template doesn't escape the `<br/>` tags

```
errors = ["error1 msg", "error2 msg", "error3 msg"]
flash[:error] = errors.join("<br/>").html_safe
```

Also, if you have an object with errors, you can use `full_messages` to get nicely formatted errors. Something like this:

```
flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>").html_safe
```

Answer (score 5):

Browsers usually ignore line breaks in HTML. Perhaps joining the errors with a line-break `<br/>` tag will have the desired effect.

```
flash[:error] = errors.join("<br/>")
```

Though it may make more sense semantically to put the errors in an unordered list (`<ul>`) and put each error in its own list item (`<li>`). Your call.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Now it displays "error1 msg<br/>error2 msg<br/>error3 msg"

Comment: It does work, but Rails is probably sanitizing the `<br/>` trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving this when you set the flash values, I think it makes more sense to change your `erb` for outputting the flash to handle newlines. There is the nice `TextHelper::simple_format(str)` (see https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) to do this:

```rb
<% if flash.any? %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <% Array(value).each do |message| %>
      <%= simple_format(message, wrapper_tag: "div", class: "alert alert-#{error_key}") %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```